# when using android room typeconverters is it possible to access the entity and field name inside the typeconverter implementation

Tags: android, android-room

I am investigating android room typeconverters and would like to know if its possible to obtain the  entity and entity field names the typeconverter is associated with.

the typeconverter annotation is marked as binary so is not available to reflection in addition it doesnt appear to have any useful additional fields.

is there any approach i can employ to identify which entity and entity field the typeconverter is associated with at runtime? i wish to obtain the string name of both the entity and entity field

i cannot see how to achieve this, i cannot pass names into the entity field declaration and the typeconverters are declared in my apps database